# How to count frequency of specific positive/negative words from a list in a .csv file with text and date values? in R

Tags: r, list, csv, count, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to get the sentiment from a document containing messages, the specific user and date. I have cleaned both documents so that the words contained in them are of a standard format and then I tried to count them but I seem to be able on to count them separately (after defining the word) but not with the use of a list of words.

the file. raw is in the format: text,user_id, date and the positive/ negative lists are in the format: id,word_cz, polarity

```r
file.raw <- read.csv("/Users/tomas/Desktop/Repromeda - Repromeda 3.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,)
positive <- read.csv("/Users/tomas/Desktop/positive.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,)
negative <- read.csv("/Users/tomas/Desktop/negative.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,)
```

I can count the specific words like "Okay" with the function

```r
getCount <- function(data,keywords)
{
  wordcount <- str_count(file.raw&text, keywords)
  return(data.frame(data,wordcount))
}
file.raw$count <-  getCount(file.raw&text,"okay")
```

)but I can't seem to find a way to automate this process with the list of words

The ideal results would add a column for each positive and negative counts to each row

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example? Also, this may help: https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
library(stringr)
data <- "yes i had a great time yesterday having fun but your lame actions were disturbing, ok?"
positive <- c("yes" , "ok", "fun", "great")
negative <- c("lame" , "disturbing", "no") 

sapply(positive, function(x) str_count(data,x))
sapply(negative, function(x) str_count(data,x))
```